# windows taskbar and open programs

Tags: windows, taskbar

Is there any way to place the taksbar icons of all the open apps in Windows 8.1 next to each other automatically?
Say I open an app whose icon is on the far left, next to the start button, and I want said icon to appear to move to the far right of my string of icons, next to all my other open programs, automatically.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean, for applications that you have already pinned to the taskbar, you want them to move over to the end of the line of open programs? I don't think it is possible to set this option automatically. However, you can manually move them to where-ever and they will remain pinned. For other taskbar settings, just search Taskbar and the settings box will come up.